# How to insert Chinese characters in the following template?

Tags: characters

I download a template from the website. But I cannot use Chinese characters in it. `\usepackage{charter}` this is the font it uses I think. I changed it but it did not work. I also change `\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm}`. But I failed too. I hope I can get any suggestion here.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Long Lined Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (1/6/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Matthew J. Miller
% http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt] % Date
123 Broadway \\ % Address
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life. 

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, are you struggling with this specific template, or are you struggling with getting chines characters in general?

Comment: I am struggling to use chinese character in this template. I change some places. But it does not work. I hope I could seek any solution from here.Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fandol fonts available with my TeX Live installation i can insert chinese characters without trouble. As they are Open-Type fonts, package `fontspec` is needed. That also means, compilation has to be done with XeTeX or LuaTeX, pdfTeX won't work here.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} 

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} 
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} 
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} 
\PhrPhone{Phone} 
\PhrEmail{Email} 


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolFang}

\namefrom{Walzing Wombat} 

\addrfrom{
    Duckburg
}

\greetto{Hey} 
\closeline{Keep Cooking} 

\nameto{Chef} 

\addrto{
    Cooking alley
}


\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

    湯 and 福

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. There is an error. ! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
! 
! The key property '.choice_code:n' is unknown.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.I update my packages but I still have it.

Comment: Just make an update of your TeX distribution, the error will go away :-)

Comment: @user18481  Does everything work? The system now can show chines characters, you can copy/paste/compile the example above :-)